# ACCESS: Need to Show Name of User along with User ID in Report

Tags: database, ms-access

[Screenshot of Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmQSB.png)

So above is the screenshot of the report. However, only the User ID prints in the report. I want it to also show the name of the user that ID corresponds to. So when my boss prints it out, he doesn't have to look up which ID that belongs to. I was able to do it with the form, with the combo box, I was able to pull this off as I used a combo box to select the user with the ID, but I am not sure how to pull it off in this regard.
[ComboBox pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7PRK.png)

Would appreciate some guidance and help on this issue!

Comment: In short use a combo box bound to userid to display the user name.  right click the bound textbox with User ID in the Detail section.  Select change to combobox.  then go through the tutorial starting at this link.  https://www.techonthenet.com/access/tutorials/combobasics2010/basics04.php

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. use combobox on report - it will look like textbox in Report or PrintPreview views
2. build a query that joins tables and use that as RecordSource.